# I am getting user data which I need to manually validate and then send it to a django model to save in the database after manual validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

i am getting user data from a Django form which i need to validate manually and then save it to django model database, the problem is that validation might take 24-48 hours. How do i hold the data temporarily so that when validated that data can be sent to the database using django models automatically, is there any functionality in django which will allow me to do that, if not how to do it.

Comment: Just have a field in the model that says `Validated = BooleanField(default=False)` then update to true once you have validated it.

Answer (score -1):

I would save in the database but without activating the user, it will prevent creating other users with this email address and other similar problems.